# Views Filter nodes and show referencing nodes

Tags: entities, views

I have 2 content types: HotelPack and Event

The HotelPack content type has an entity reference field that references to an Event

In the view I want to show all the Events and filter them by Category (using an exposed filter)

I also want to show in the View all the HotelPacks that contain the matching Events

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: It looks straightforward to me, specify a relationship in Views. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, you have to create the relationship.
In views go to advanced, then you will see relationships, add the entity referenced field there, in filter add the field you want to filter and there will be a relationship select option above, this way you are telling the view that you want to filter by the field that has the referenced and you explicity placed in the relationship.